# Call a variable outside of a function?

Tags: python, function

For example:

```
def test(a)
   a = 2
   b = 5+a
   x = a*2
   return x
```

Is there a way to call the variable 'b' outside of the function?

Comment: Make it `global`? Or return it as well (remember that in Python you can return multiple values).

Comment: or return both things if you need both things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = None

    def test(a)
       global b
       a = 2
       b = 5+a
       x = a*2
       return x

print(b)
```

Although we will suggest to return `b` and then access it, as global variable is a bad idea.
See this,
[Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)